# Animation effect is at the bottom part of my screen when it should be over the whole screen

Tags: javascript, animation

I have been trying this udemy project and want to put some confetti animation once the answer is correct. However, the animation is going at the bottom part of my screen. How can I move the confetti at the body of my whole screen?

I attached below the picture of what it looks like when executed and the js code of the confetti part. Thanks!

[image: Confetti animation picture]

Please see the code for reference:

```js
let maxParticleCount = 150; //set max confetti count
let particleSpeed = 2; //set the particle animation speed
let startConfetti; //call to start confetti animation
let stopConfetti; //call to stop adding confetti
let toggleConfetti; //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
let removeConfetti; //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately

(function () {
  startConfetti = startConfettiInner;
  stopConfetti = stopConfettiInner;
  toggleConfetti = toggleConfettiInner;
  removeConfetti = removeConfettiInner;
  let colors = [
    'DodgerBlue',
    'OliveDrab',
    'Gold',
    'Pink',
    'SlateBlue',
    'LightBlue',
    'Violet',
    'PaleGreen',
    'SteelBlue',
    'SandyBrown',
    'Chocolate',
    'Crimson',
  ];
  let streamingConfetti = false;
  let animationTimer = null;
  let particles = [];
  let waveAngle = 0;

  function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
    particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0];
    particle.x = Math.random() * width;
    particle.y = Math.random() * height - height;
    particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
    particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
    particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
    particle.tiltAngle = 0;
    return particle;
  }

  function startConfettiInner() {
    let width = window.innerWidth;
    let height = window.innerHeight;
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
      return (
        window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
          return window.setTimeout(callback, 16.6666667);
        }
      );
    })();
    let canvas = document.getElementById('confetti-canvas');
    if (canvas === null) {
      canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.setAttribute('id', 'confetti-canvas');
      canvas.setAttribute(
        'style',
        'display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none'
      );
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      window.addEventListener(
        'resize',
        function () {
          canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
          canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        },
        true
      );
    }
    let context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    while (particles.length < maxParticleCount)
      particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
    streamingConfetti = true;
    if (animationTimer === null) {
      (function runAnimation() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        if (particles.length === 0) animationTimer = null;
        else {
          updateParticles();
          drawParticles(context);
          animationTimer = requestAnimFrame(runAnimation);
        }
      })();
    }
  }

  function stopConfettiInner() {
    streamingConfetti = false;
  }

  function removeConfettiInner() {
    stopConfetti();
    particles = [];
  }

  function toggleConfettiInner() {
    if (streamingConfetti) stopConfettiInner();
    else startConfettiInner();
  }

  function drawParticles(context) {
    let particle;
    let x;
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      particle = particles[i];
      context.beginPath();
      context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
      context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
      x = particle.x + particle.tilt;
      context.moveTo(x + particle.diameter / 2, particle.y);
      context.lineTo(x, particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2);
      context.stroke();
    }
  }

  function updateParticles() {
    let width = window.innerWidth;
    let height = window.innerHeight;
    let particle;
    waveAngle += 0.01;
    for (let i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      particle = particles[i];
      if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15) particle.y = height + 100;
      else {
        particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
        particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle);
        particle.y +=
          (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + particleSpeed) * 0.5;
        particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
      }
      if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
        if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= maxParticleCount)
          resetParticle(particle, width, height);
        else {
          particles.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron:wght@600&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  user-select: none;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: #222;
  /* background-color: #60b347; */
}

/* LAYOUT */
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 35vh;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #eee;
}

main {
  height: 65vh;
  color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.left {
  width: 52rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.right {
  width: 52rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

/* ELEMENTS STYLE */
h1 {
  font-size: 6rem;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 52%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.number {
  background: #eee;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 6rem;
  width: 15rem;
  padding: 3rem 0rem;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.between {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  right: 2rem;
}

.again {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2rem;
  left: 2rem;
}

.guess {
  background: none;
  border: 4px solid #eee;
  font-family: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  font-size: 5rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  width: 22rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: inherit;
  padding: 2rem 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.message {
  margin-bottom: 8rem;
  height: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.label-score {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Guess My Number!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="confetti.js"></script>
    <header>
      <h1>Guess My Number!</h1>
      <p class="between">(Between 1 and 20)</p>
      <button class="btn again">Again!</button>
      <div class="number">?</div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <section class="left">
        <input type="number" class="guess" />
        <button class="btn check">Check!</button>
      </section>
      <section class="right">
        <p class="message">Start guessing...</p>
        <p class="label-score"> Score: <span class="score">15</span></p>
        <p class="label-highscore">
           Highscore: <span class="highscore">0</span>
        </p>
      </section>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in your html code you do not have the canvas element, but create it in the js code like this:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// ...
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

This code adds the `canvas` element at the end of the `body`:

```
<body>
<header>...</header>
<main>...</main>
<canvas >
</body>
```

In your css you do not have styling for this specific canvas, hence it gets pushed underneath the `header` and `main` elements (for which you do have styling in the css) following the normal block elements css rules for possitioning.

**So your solution** would be to add this to the style.css:

```
#confetti-canvas {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Which will make the confetti canvas start from top of the screen and be positioned absolutely (normally for such kind of overlays you would want to have **absolute** positioning).

Comment: Thank you! That helps! But do you know how I could stop the confetti execution once I hit the again button?